# Looking for a free way to add breadcrumbs to my website, I still haven't found a consistent way with YOAST SEO on my Elementor Pro website

Tags: wordpress, elementor, breadcrumbs, yoast

So I have been trying with Rank Math, Yoast, with the little code embedded, but nothing seems to be clear in terms of letting WordPress/Elementor the structure of my website, which parent pages after the home have children, etc. I would be grateful if someone could guide me through this task of adding these important Breadcrumbs.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Elementor Pro, you can implement breadcrumbs by adding the following shortcode: `[wpseo_breadcrumb]`. This works seamlessly when you have the Yoast SEO plugin installed.

Alternatively, if you prefer a custom solution without using a plugin, you can follow these steps outlined in this guide: [How to Create Custom Breadcrumbs in WordPress Without a Plugin](https://shubhamverma.com/how-to-create-custom-breadcrumbs-in-wordpress-without-a-plugin/).